# Some doubts about how work this particular query of a delete from a list predicate

Tags: prolog

I have a doubt about how work this query for this **del/3** predicate:

```
/* BASE CASE: If I delete X from List and X is the HEAD of List, NewList is
              the Tail of List
*/
del(X, [X|Tail], Tail).

/* GENERAL CASE: If the head of List is not X then the program have to delete
                 X in the Tail of List
*/
del(X, [Y|Tail], [Y|Tail1]) :- del(X, Tail, Tail1).
```

The predicate logic is very simple: delete X item form a list creating a new list without X: if X is in the head of the list the newlist is its tail. Otherwise, if the X item is not in the head of the list, try to find it (and delete) in the Tail creating a new tail Tail1.

Ok, so I have no problem with the predicate logic but I am having some problem trying to understand how work this query (I have to use it in another program):

```
del([Top1|Stack1], [[a,b,c],[],[]], Stacks1).
```

So this query have to delete **[Top1|Stack1]** from **[[a,b,c],[],[]]** that is a list of stacks (in this particular case I have 3 stacks: [a,b,c] and 2 empty stacks: []) generating so a new list of stacks named **Stacks1**

If I try to execute a trace of the query I obtain this:

```
[trace]  ?- del([Top1|Stack1], [[a,b,c],[],[]], Stacks1).
   Call: (7) del([_G389|_G390], [[a, b, c], [], []], _G412) ? creep
   Exit: (7) del([a, b, c], [[a, b, c], [], []], [[], []]) ? creep
Top1 = a,
Stack1 = [b, c],
Stacks1 = [[], []] .
```

I have some difficulties to understand why: **[Top1|Stack1]** is unified with the first stack **[a, b, c]**

EDIT:
I think that maybe work in this way: The list of Stacks is: **[[a,b,c],[],[]]** that is a **list of lists** wherein the first list is: **[a,b,c]** (that is the **head** of this list of list**

So when I write: **[Top1|Stack1]** happens that:

**Top1 = [a,b,c]**
**Stack1 = [[],[]]**

So happens that **Top1** is the **first stack in the stacks list** and **Stack1** is the list of others stacks.

So when I write the predicate:

```
 del([Top1|Stack1], Stacks, Stacks1).
```

(where, for example: **Stacks = [[a,b,c],[],[]]**)

It work in this way:

It unifiest Top1 with the first stack in stack list: **[a,b,c]** and delete it from **Stacks** list...

My dount is related on Prolog semantic viz when I execute a simple query as:

```
del(b, [a,b,c], NewList).
```

it delete b item from the list and NewList=[a,c]

but when I have that the field of the item that have be delete is something like: **[Head|Tail]** is it the Head item that have be to deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query `D=[[a,b,c],[],[]], del([A|B], D, C)` picks any list matching `[A|B]` from among `D`'s elements. The only possibility here is `[A|B]=[a,b,c]` and the leftovers are `C=[[],[]]`.

In general `del` fully backtracks, finding all possibilities one by one. Here there is only one possibility.

To better understand `del`, try this:

```
2 ?- del(X,[A,B,C],D).
X = A,
D = [B, C] ;
X = B,
D = [A, C] ;
X = C,
D = [A, B] ;
false.
```

It isn't trying to "find" `X`; it's just picking it one by one from among the possibilities (the 2nd argument). That's what the predicate says that it is / does.

Of course *if* the lists are instantiated to ground terms, some might not match and will be rejected, creating an impression of a value being searched for:

```
4 ?- del(b, [a,b,c,d], R).
R = [a, c, d] ;
false.

5 ?- del(b, [a,b,X,d], R).
R = [a, X, d] ;
X = b,
R = [a, b, d] ;
false.
```

The term `[A|B]` just matches any non-empty list (or a logical variable):

```
6 ?- del([A|B], [[a],b,X,d], R).
A = a,
B = [],
R = [b, X, d] ;
X = [A|B],
R = [[a], b, d] ;
false.

7 ?- del([A|B], [[a],b,[],d], R).
A = a,
B = [],
R = [b, [], d] ;
false.
```

So e.g. `del([A|B], [[1,2,3], [4,5], [], [6]], R)` will pick any non-empty list from the 4 lists given in the 2nd argument of this sample call, and while it does that, it will bind `A` to the head element and `B` to the rest of elements of the list that was picked.

This predicate is known as [`select/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=select%2F3) in the wild. :)

---

Illustration:

```
del(X, [X|Tail], Tail).

     X        X
     --------------------
              T        T
              a        a
              i        i
              l        l

del(X, [Y|Tail], [Y|Tail1]) :- del(X, Tail, Tail1).

              Y        Y
     --------------------
              T        T
       /      .        a
     X -      .        i
       \      .        l
              .        1
              l
```

Comment: Now the situation semmes to me more clear. I have also proceeded to see the select/3 predicate and yes have the same behavior.

So the very last question about it (to be sure that I have understand well):

When I do something like: del([A|B], [[1,2,3], [4,5], [], [6]], R) what happens is that: first time [A|B] match with a list that can be decomposed in an head and a tail, so delete this list and give me the rest lists. So for example I obtain: R = [[4, 5], [], [6]] in the prolog shell. Then if I insert ; character in the Prolog shell I force backtrack and I say to the program that have to

Comment: search for another list that can unfied with the form [A|B], so in the previous case [A|B] is unified with the list [4, 5] that is deleted form the list of lists and so the rest is R = [[1, 2, 3], [], [6]] and so on according to the classic logic of backtrack...
Is it right?

Tnx so much

Comment: Yeahhh !!! Unfortunately, not having been able to follow the lessons (due to work) I have to break the boxes here :-)